# How to pass images created by GUI1 to GUI2?

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I've got a problem about passing images.

I've created two GUIs, one for processing data(GUI1) and the other for producing different kinds of images.(GUI2)

I've tried using setappdata/getappdata for passing variables then plot them in GUI2. However, there's some different groups of my data so I use for loop in GUI1 to separate them. Thus, if I used setappdata, it would only pass one set of variable.

My idea is plotting all images in GUI1 then extracting them in GUI2 so I tried to use setappdata/getappdata to save image handles. However, it would only pass the integer but not the image.

Here's my code:

In GUI1

```
for i = 1:3
   h=figure(); plot(...); 
   setappdata(0,strcat('h',num2str(i)),h);
end
```

In GUI2

```
for i = 1:3
  i = getappdata(0,strcat('h',num2str(i)));
end
```

then it would show `i = 1; i = 2; i = 3;`

Can I extract images without saving them into disk?